# .Net Winforms Analytics

Tags: c#, winforms, google-analytics-api

I have a .net winforms application and I want to integrate logging like Google Analytics. I really would like to avoid building my own as that would take so much time and would be less detailed compared to what GA can give us. I tried searching but I haven't found one yet maybe the community can point me into the right direction.

Comment: Google analytics is a "web analytics service". I'm not sure why you would think that could be used with a desktop app. There might be libraries available that can give you something similar for a desktop app, but if you want recommendations => https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/